# ruby regex string $

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to cut the price from strings like that:

```
s1 = "somefing $ 100"
s2 = "$       19081 words $"
s3 = "30$"
s4 = "hi $90"
s5 = "wow 150"
```

Output should be:

```
s1 = "100"
s2 = "19081"
s3 = "30"
s4 = "90"
s5 = nil
```

I use the following regex:

```
price = str[/\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/, 1]
```

But it doesn't work for all types of strings.

Comment: See [here](http://rubular.com/r/lFonaEzvH6). Your regex should work.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I'm getting nil for this string in Ruby: "url 350 $". I don't know how to set new string to data captured in regex. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, I I copy/paste that in the rubular example it seems to work just fine. Try to post some reproducible example.

Comment: str[/\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/, 1] - this does not work.

Comment: Top tip: the case your code doesn't work for should be part of the question

Comment: Do you really want to re-define your string variables when getting the answer? Or do you want the answers in new variables? i.e. the price from s1 in a new variable p1? And are you sure want the prices as strings?

Comment: in new variable p1 as strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code always returns the result of the first capture group group whereas in the failing case it is the second capture group that you are interested in. I don't think the `[]` method has a good way of dealing with this (when using numbered capture groups). You could write this like so

```
price = str =~ /\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/ && ($1 || $2)
```

Although this isn't very legible. If instead you use a named capture group, then you can do

```
price = str[/\$\s*(?<amount>\d+)|(?<amount>\d+)\s*\$/, 'amount']
```

Duplicate named capture groups won't always do what you want but when they are in separate alternation branches (as they are here) then it should work.

Comment: That's it. I knew there's some elegant Ruby way to write conditional for groups :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're always getting value from the first regex group and you don't check the second. So, you're not looking the case after `|` - the one when digit is before `$` sign.

If you look at [the graphical representation](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5C%24%5Cs*(%5Cd%2B)%7C(%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%5C%24%2F) of your regex, by typing `1` as a second parameter in square brackets, you are covering only the upper path (first case), and you never check lower one (second case).

Basically, try:

```
price = str[/\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/, 1] or str[/\$\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\$/, 2]
```

P.S. I'm not that experienced in Ruby, there might be some more optimal way to type this, but this should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

try this, its much simpler but it may not be the most efficient.

```
p1 = s1.gsub(' ','')[/\$(\d+)|(\d+)\$/,1]
```